# is there a better way to align this column of numbers in a Swift textView?

Tags: arrays, swift, char, textview

I need to format a column of numbers in `textView` by displaying a column of fractional and decimal numbers and aligning them so the decimal point or forward slash characters appear in the same column like so ...

```
    x      1/1
    1     76.04900
    x    193.15686
    x    310.26471
    4      5/4
    x    503.42157
    6    579.47057
    x    696.57843
    x     25/16
    9    889.73529
    x   1006.84314
    11  1082.89214
```

This was achieved in Swift by inserting the appropriate number of leading whitespace characters and using left justification with a font where the column width is the same for each character.

To calculate the number of whitespaces, characters in the remainder or the dividend are excluded from the total number of characters in each number. This simple task involved subtracting `.index(of: )` from `.count` and was complicated by the fact that `.index(of:)` returns an optional `Array.Index?` not an `Int?`

I suspect there might be a simpler way to achieve the same result and welcome any improvements to the Swift code *below* that might make life easier for whoever has to maintain it. The code was extracted from my project and has been tested in Playground.

Note. `textMessage` is a single string. It is currently displayed in the Debug area. It will eventually be displayed in a `textView`.

```
//: Playground

    import UIKit

    var tuningArray            = ["1/1", "76.04900", "193.15686", "310.26471", "5/4", "503.42157", "579.47057", "696.57843", "25/16", "889.73529", "1006.84314", "1082.89214"]
    var keyArray               = ["x", "1", "x", "x", "4", "x", "6", "x", "x", "9", "x", "11"]

    var characterCountArray    = [Int]()
    var scaleSize              = Int()
    var textMessage            = String()



    func formatTextMessage() {
    var formattedTextArray     = [String](repeating: "", count: scaleSize)

    for i in 0..<scaleSize  {
        let element            = tuningArray[i]
        countNumericCharactersBeforeDotOrSlash (s: element)
        }

    let largestStringSize      = characterCountArray.reduce(Int.min, { max($0, $1) })

    for i in 0..<scaleSize {

        let thisStringSize     = characterCountArray[i]
        let blanks             = largestStringSize - thisStringSize
        let filler             = insertWhiteSpace(count: blanks)

        formattedTextArray[i].append("\t" + keyArray[i] + "\t" + filler + tuningArray[i] + "\n")
        textMessage            += formattedTextArray[i]
        }
    print(textMessage)
    }



    func insertWhiteSpace(count: Int) -> String {
    var filler                 = ""
        for _ in 0..<count {
        filler                 = filler + " "
        }
    return filler
    }



    func countNumericCharactersBeforeDotOrSlash (s: String) {

    let fractionalNumber       = findFractionalNumber(s: s)
    let decimalNumber          = findDecimalNumber(s: s)
    var thisStringSize         = 0

    if !fractionalNumber && !decimalNumber {
        print("Error: invalid number format")
    }

    if fractionalNumber        == true {

    let pitchStringArray       = Array(s.characters)
    let endIndex               = pitchStringArray.count

    if let slashIndex          = pitchStringArray.index(of: "/") {
        let dividendFiller     = endIndex - slashIndex
        thisStringSize         = s.characters.count - dividendFiller
    }

    } else {

    if decimalNumber           == true {

        let pitchStringArray   = Array(s.characters)
        let endIndex           = pitchStringArray.count

        if let dotIndex        = pitchStringArray.index(of: ".") {
           let remainderFiller = endIndex - dotIndex
            thisStringSize     = s.characters.count - remainderFiller
            }
         }
      }
    characterCountArray.append(thisStringSize)
    }



    func findDecimalNumber(s: String?) -> Bool {
    if (s?.contains("."))      == true   {
        return true
        }
        return false
    }



    func findFractionalNumber(s: String?) -> Bool {
    if (s?.contains("/"))      == true   {
        return true
        }
        return false
    }



    scaleSize                  = tuningArray.count
    formatTextMessage()
```

Comment: Greg, Do you want to align your text like above? to look like tabular formate?

Comment: Yes. Similar to Word or Excel except numbers need to be aligned on the decimal or forward slash column to conform to the scales standard used in Scala (see http://www.huygens-fokker.org/microtonality/scales.html)

Comment: All your decimal numbers have to be aligned same like above image? i.e all "." must be in line.

Comment: Yes. And all "/" too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use attributed text with custom tab stops, like in this example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


var tuningArray            = ["1/1", "76.04900", "193.15686", "310.26471", "5/4", "503.42157", "579.47057", "696.57843", "25/16", "889.73529", "1006.84314", "1082.89214"]

var keyArray    = ["x", "1", "x", "x", "4", "x", "6", "x", "x", "9", "x", "11"]
let scaleSize   = tuningArray.count
var textMessage = ""

for i in 0..<scaleSize {
    var textLine = "\t" + keyArray[i] + "\t" + tuningArray[i] + "\n"
    textMessage  += textLine
}

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
let decimalTerminators:CharacterSet = [".", "/"]
let decimalTabOptions = [NSTabColumnTerminatorsAttributeName:decimalTerminators]
let decimalTabLocation = CGFloat(100) // TODO: Calculate...
var decimalTab = NSTextTab(textAlignment: .natural, location: decimalTabLocation, options: decimalTabOptions)
var leftTab = NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: CGFloat(0.01), options: [:])
paragraphStyle.tabStops = [leftTab, decimalTab]

var a = NSAttributedString(string:textMessage,attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle])

let tv = UITextView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:400, height:200))
tv.attributedText = a
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = tv
```

The only drawback is, that you have to calculate the position of the decimal tab somehow; in the example I just use `CGFloat(100)` to get a nice value. But maybe you could simply live with a constant like this.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Andreas, you've made this look much simpler than my original code. Thanks. I am now trying it to get it working in the Xcode project in the ViewController where tv will appear inside a StackViewController. Swift is still new for me so I need more time to check this answer thoroughly. Be assured I'll get back to you as soon as I'm confident about accepting it.

Comment: Andreas, you're a gem! Your solution reduced my code to a single function that now works in my Xcode project. This has to be the accepted answer.

Comment: Andreas, I've taken this further but it's not quite there. If you can spare a moment, please take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/q/42298647/2348597 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Greg,
Instead of using space to set columns use tab (\t) tree for times based on columns size you need.
That will help to manage code better way with very less and powerful coding.

Thanks

Comment: Ashwin, do you mean using `"\t"` only, instead of `"\t" + filler` ? - like I have in `formattedTextArray[i].append("\t" + keyArray[i] + "\t" + filler + tuningArray[i] + "\n")`

Comment: Yes, you can manage it with the only \t. but single \t won't help. you have to add multiple tabs based on max text length.